# what is the drawback of sendSticyBroadcast() in Android?

Tags: broadcastreceiver, sticky

I am developing an android application in API Level 21, i am broadcasting a message but some unusual things happens. like another application can using it.

Can anyone help me out in How to send a Sticky Broadcast in API 21.

```
    //MyActivity.java
    class myActivity extends Activity {

    //MyDialog dialog initialized in onCreate

    ...

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //toast "Broadcast received"
        }
    }
}

//MyDialog.java
class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    //m_context = incoming context from MyActivity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                m_context.sendStickyBroadcast(intent);
            }

       });

    }

}


//AndroidManifest.xml
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" />
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.RUN"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: i also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/> - Allows an application to broadcast sticky intents.

Comment: - normal broadcast intent is not available any more after is was send and processed by the system.

:- use sendStickyBroadcast(Intent)

:- the corresponding intent is sticky, meaning the intent you are sending stays around after the broadcast is complete.

:- because of this others can quickly retrieve that data through the return value of registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter).

:- apart from this same as sendBroadcast(Intent).

Answer (score 0):

Yes i have foud he answer after googling a lot.

**This method was deprecated in API level 21. Sticky broadcasts should not be used. They provide no security (anyone can access them), no protection (anyone can modify them), and many other problems. The recommended pattern is to use a non-sticky broadcast to report that something has changed, with another mechanism for apps to retrieve the current value whenever desired.**